# Cannot upload videos to my own Youtube account using plain PHP

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, composer-php, google-oauth

I'm using plain `PHP`. I'm not using any `PHP` framework like `Lavarel`, `Symphony`, `Wordpress`, etc.

I need to upload a video to my own `Youtube` account.

Just in case, I want to clarify that what I want is `NOT` create a `Youtube` application to upload a video to a user's account on behalf of that `Youtube` user like in normal `Facebook` apps.

I found this official guide:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/php

and as recommended, I created a new project under:

https://console.developers.google.com/start/api?id=youtube

but I'm a bit confused about this.

My questions are:

- why do I need to create a project under the Google API console if I just want to upload files to my own account?, should not be enough with Youtube `user` and `password`?. If I need to create a project and then generate an access token, how long is valid that access token?
- I tried the following code which is not exactly to uplaod videos (what I need), but at least it supposed to help me start playing with Youtube:

  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#example

which I adapted a bit to:

```
<?php
// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/utils.inc.php';

$path_youtube_credentials = __DIR__.'/_debug/credentials/youtube.credentials.json';
$path_youtube_accesstoken = __DIR__.'/_debug/credentials/youtube.accesstoken.txt';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($path_youtube_credentials);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE_READONLY);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setConfig('defaults', [
    'verify' => __DIR__.'/includes/cacert.pem',
]);

if (file_exists($path_youtube_accesstoken)) {
    $accessToken = trim(file_get_contents($path_youtube_accesstoken));
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
    $channel = $youtube->channels->listChannels('snippet', array('mine' => true));
    echoc(json_encode($channel));
}
else {
    $client->setRedirectUri(get_protocol().'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/youtube.callback.php');
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: '.$authUrl);
}
?>
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in '.\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php'
```

Any idea on how can I upload videos to `Youtube`?

Comment: Google usually goes overboard with it's security and credentials. You have to 'register' your application to use their APIs, and then you have to get an OAuth 2.0 refresh token and access token. You register the app so Google can shut it down if they feel you are abusing their system, or they just want to censor you. The access token lasts about an hour (?), and the refresh token lasts 'forever'. Their API handles the OAuth authentication. Your error looks like you need the CA chain - certificate authority chain for root certificate issuers. Can you make HTTPS curl requests from shell?